# Topologic Embedding

Tags: general-topology

I have this problems

1. Proof that the ball $B_1{(0,0)}$ can be embedded in Moore plane (Niemytzki plane)
2. Proof that $({\mathbb R}^3; \textrm{usual topology})$ can be embedded in Moore plane (Niemytzki plane)
3. Proof that $({\mathbb R}; \textrm{usual topology})$ can be embedded in Moore plane (Niemytzki plane)
   For the second I dont know if the function $h(x)=\left(x,\arctan(x)+ \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ is right.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first part should be easy via $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y+1)$, the third via $x\mapsto (x,1)$.

However, I doubt that the second statement is true:
Assume $f\colon \mathbb R^3\to \Gamma$ is an embedding. If there is a point $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^3$ such that $f(p)=(u,v)$ has $v>0$, then there is an open 3D ball around $(x,y)$ that is embedded into an open disc in $\mathbb R^2$. This is not possible (though I'd need homology to show that). Therefore $f(\mathbb R^3)\subseteq \{(u,v)\in\Gamma\mid v=0\}$, but the latter set is discrete.

**Edit:** after the second part is changed from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R^2$, the statement is clear: $\mathbb R$ is homeomorphic to an open interval, e.g.  $(-1,1)$, hence $\mathbb R^2$ to $(0,1)^2$, which can be placed inside $\Gamma$.

Comment: My fault it is ${\mathbb R}^2$

Comment: Then please edit the question.